# Scala: Illegal start of simple pattern when pattern matching on list item with if statement

Tags: scala

I would like to do pattern matching on list items using if statements. However, I get an error at the space before my if statement saying "Illegal start of simple pattern". What would be the correct way to implement pattern matching on list items with IF statements?

```
def myMethod(xs: List[Int]): Int= {

xs match {
    case Nil => 0

    case i :: if (i % 2 == 0) => i
  }


}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `myMethod`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `_` before the guard `if`

```
def myMethod(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => 0
  case i :: _ if (i % 2 == 0) => i
}
```

Comment: Why do I need a _ here?

Comment: Because you want to ignore the tail and only consider head of the list

Comment: @Csanád Because `::` needs two operands. `i ::` is not a legal pattern because it's missing a right operand. The `if` doesn't really have anything to do with it - `case i :: => i` would be a syntax error, too.